RUST curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
I am new to rust . Trying make a simple backend with RUST.
But I am getting this error again and again. Tried to solve this with the help of resources.
this is my main.rs
use actix_web::{web::Path, get, HttpServer, App, Responder};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
   let server= HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(home)
            .service(hello_user)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1",8000))?
    .run();
    println!("Server Running at 127");

     server.await 
    
}

#[get("/home")]
async fn home() -> impl Responder {
    let response: &str = "Welcome to actix server";
    response
}

#[get("/hello/{firstname}/{lastname}")]
async fn hello_user(params: Path<(String, String)>) -> impl Responder {
    let response: String = format!("Hello {} {}", params.0, params.1);
    response
}

this cargo.toml file
[package]
name = "web-actix-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.2.1"

when I run this command

curl 127.0.0.1:8000/home

I get this error

curl : Unable to connect to the remote server


Your code works fine, please add more details how you run it and your environment so it's reproducible.

Cannot reproduce, check firewall setting

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Actix Web" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8000
used this
But still not working

best firewall is no firewall we are in 2024 :p

Any tips on how to acitvate port for actix web
Its seems in windows its already active
But when I run the program it doesn't connect

emmm，you can try
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

and you need to check whether your firewall and ports are running properly.
lsof -i:8000

